# Two TP networks with same protocol locks each other on IP side

Tags: switch, router, network

I installed a lighting automation system for a football stadium. There are two separate networks based on KNX protocol and those networks are just created with twisted pair cables jumping through all devices in line. Not LAN network. I used two pieces of KNX-specific IP converters, which just carry those TP networks into IP segment. These IP converters are just interface changers , and not routers. But there are specific KNX-IP routers for this task also, which i did not try yet. Well, for purpose of connecting these two networks into computer , I used a good quality unmanaged switch. But when i open the related software for communication as a whole, I see there are locks and communication is healthy only for a couple of seconds. When i unplug one of the networks from switch, the other plugged network works like a charm. So, I will have several options left to solve this issue. But each one of them is another money. So i need to select the most accurate one.

1. Using a router instead of unmanaged switch
2. Using a managed switch instead of unmanaged switch
3. Changing KNX-IP interface converters with KNX-IP routers.

I am looking forward to your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both IP converters need to have their own IP address (and their own MAC address) when plugged into a single network. Additionally, I'm assuming that such a converter adheres to Ethernet (802.3) and IP standards (IETF).

Edit after comment:

From what I could find quickly [1](https://www.weinzierl.de/images/download/products/730/KNX_over_IP_DE.pdf), a "KNX-IP converter" is only suitable for connecting to a single NIC. For connecting to a network/switch you seem to need an "KNX-IP router". From the network perspective these labels don't make much sense, but as it seems only a "router" adheres to common network standards (ie. has a complete layer 3 implementation).

Since KNX uses no freely available specifications, this question seems to be off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: Of course, those converters are assigned different static ip addresses

Comment: I used a KNX IP router and problem is solved